# git subtree push failed for behind its remote counterpart

Tags: github, github-pages, git-subtree

I have a github repository and wanted to make a mockup live with my domain.

Since the index.html is located inside a folder named "development" (but not directly in the root), what I did was

a. Create another github repo called "USERNAME.github.io"

b. Add the remote-url by

```
git remote add demo-origin git@github.com:USERNAME/USERNAME.github.io.git
```

c. push the repo subtree "development" by

```
git subtree push --prefix development demo-origin master
```

d. create "CNAME" file in my "USERNAME.github.io"

e. update the DNS to match the CNAME

Now everything works fine. However when I want to push updates again, I got the error message:

```
git push using:  demo-origin master
To git@github.com:SMARTEDU/SMARTEDU.github.io.git
! [rejected]        a5f0176dc6e0b10fa77a88cffe89a67d087d1f96 -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:SMARTEDU/SMARTEDU.github.io.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

This was due to the CNAME file added in "USERNAME.github.io" repo, but even if I pull it to local, it is still failed when I want to do `git subtree push --prefix development demo-origin master` again.

Any idea on how to fix it? Very appreciate!